# Azure SQL Server - Allow Role Access to Database via SSMS

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, ssms

I want to allow developers to connect to a specific databases on our Azure SQL Server. I've read all the Microsoft documentation I can find and a bunch of useful blog posts but can't find an answer to this question.

I've created a user and added the user to the db_owner role for the database is question. In the SSMS logon I tried both these logon but both fail:

```
<servername>.<databasename>.net,1433

<databasename>.database.net,1433
```

UPDATE: I suspect the correct answer will be: "**Don't do that**." In other words, the developers can do anything they need to do from within Visual Studio and don't need access via SSMS.

Comment: might help if you post the actual error message you're getting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the firewall in the Azure Portal allows connection from the developers' machine IP Address.  If the firewall is not the issue, and you can login with the admin account just fine, [then check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476828/new-user-cannot-login-to-sql-azure/6480825#6480825) from a previous post with a similar issue; you need to create the account in Master or specify the database name you are connecting to in the SSMS login screen.

Comment: The answer from the link you provided was exactly what I needed. Thanks!